# Azure Service Management APIs have been deprecated for messaging services as of November 1, 2021 and replaced with Azure Resource Management APIs

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I want to create a service bus to be able to debug a remote event receivers as mentioned in this link https://blog.virtosoftware.com/remote-event-receivers-creating-and-debugging-sharepoint-online/, so i tried to run this command:-

```
New-AzureSBNamespace "TestTestingServiceBus" -CreateACSNamespace $true -NamespaceType Messaging
```

but i got this error:-

```
New-AzureSBNamespace : <string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">{"Details":"Azure Service
Management APIs have been deprecated for messaging services as of November 1, 2021 and replaced with Azure Resource
Management APIs. For more information, please visit
https://azure.microsoft.com/updates/asm-api-messaging-services-retirement/"}</string>
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzureSBNamespace "TestTestingServiceBus" -CreateACSNamespace $tru ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureSBNamespace], CloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceBus.NewAzureSBNamespaceCommand
```

any advice? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are referencing a really old blog post. A lot has changed since that post was written and this is why you are getting the error.

If you want to create a new Service Bus Namespace, please use [`New-AzServiceBusNamespace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.servicebus/new-azservicebusnamespace?view=azps-10.1.0).

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the link, seems there are many settings for service bus, so which one i need to use for debugging remote event receivers.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no idea about that, sorry.